# Java for loop algorithm

Tags: java, loops

how do I make a loop that checks 1, 4 times and then moves to 2, and checks it 4 times, and moves to 3, and checks it 4 times.

For example:

```
//Btw, isNextFree is a boolean that returns true or false if the next line is free.
while(linenumber.isNextFree()){
int linenumber=1;
username = line(linenumber,usernamefile);
linenumber+=1;
}
```

So, what that loop does is it checks linenumber of usernamefile.txt and stores that value in a hashmap, I need to check use that string value in line one which is stored in that hashmap to make a 4 strings on what is on linenumber 1 on username file concatenate with 1 same passwordstring on passwordfile.txt.

By the way, I'm using scanner, so the line and linenumber.isNextFree doesn't exist, it is like scanner's .isNext basically.

Comment: This doesn't even compile (`linenumber` cannot be something **and** an `int`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I've no idea what you're trying to say. It's gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the second part of the question, for the first:

```
for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
{
    for(int j=1; j<5; j++)
    {
       //Do somethings for check
       //Example
       System.out.println("It's "+ i + " = " j ");
   }
   System.out.println(""); //only a new line like \n
}
```

With this code, it do somethings with 1, 4 times
after do something with 2, 4 times
and after do somethings with 3, 4 times

the output is:

```
    It's 1 = 1
    It's 1 = 2
    It's 1 = 3
    It's 1 = 4

    It's 2 = 1
    It's 2 = 2
    It's 2 = 3
    It's 2 = 4

    It's 3 = 1
    It's 3 = 2
    It's 3 = 3
    It's 3 = 4
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: output is always 1 to 3 not as expected by OP